# Return two hashmap values from function

Tags: java

I have created function which uses one object list and using that list it created two `HashMap` values:

```
public HashMap<HashMap<Integer, List<String>>, HashMap<Integer, List<Long>>> getIONameAndId(
        List<LineItemVO> lineItemVOs) {
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> ioNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, List<Long>> ioIdMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<HashMap<Integer, List<String>>, HashMap<Integer, List<Long>>> ioData =
        new HashMap<>();
    List<Long> ioIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    List<String> ioNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (LineItemVO lineItemVO : lineItemVOs) {
        ioIds.add(lineItemVO.getInsertionOrderId());
        ioNames.add(lineItemVO.getInsertionOrderName());
    }
    ioNameMap.put(1, ioNames);
    ioIdMap.put(1, ioIds);
    ioData.put(ioNameMap, ioIdMap);
    return ioData;
}
```

I want to simplify this function so it gives exact idea what it returns or should I use `Map` instead of `HashMap`?

Comment: I smell **object phobia**. Create a meaningful `Object` that holds your two values; if you cannot think of a meaningful object, then you have a problem with your modelling.

Comment: On another note, program to the `interface`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't understand your answer, means I can think of another modeling but I want to use this approach for problem, I want just refactoring